# Display all images from specific CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I have a CPT for "Band Members", and I want to list all of them at the top of a template, above all the posts (which will just be featured images) - a sort-of Navigation for all members. I can't think of how to do this... is there two loops? Any help would be appreciated!

```
<div id="main">
<?php


$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'band_member',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1 // WHAT IS THIS??
  );

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<div class="post-nav">'; 
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

  ?>


<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>


<?php
  endwhile;
}
echo '</div><!-- end post nav -->';

wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

?>

<?php
// PUT ALL CPT FEATURED IMAGES HERE...
?>
</div><!-- /main -->
```

END OF ORIGINAL CODE.....

NEW CODE WITH HELP.....

```
<section id="main"> 
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'band_member',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<div class="post-nav">'; 
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
echo '</div><!-- end post nav -->';

wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

?>
<?php

$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'band_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );

  $my_query = null;
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

       if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

       while ($my_query->have_posts()) :  $my_query->the_post();
       ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a> 
<?php
     endwhile;
  }

  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().

?>
            </section><!-- /#main -->
```

Comment: I don't understand why you run the same loop twice, one to display the title and one to display thumbnails

Comment: Do you want one loop with just images and one loop with just titles.

Comment: Yes, I can see how that might be confusing. It is for a listing of many members of a group. What I'm aiming for is to have the titles as a "mini nav" preceding all of the thumbnails, also to be included on single post pages of this CPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track here, but it is a bit bumpy

Firstly, `caller_get_posts` is depreciated, that has been replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

Secondly, you should use `wp_reset_postdata` not `wp_reset_query`. The latter is used in conjuction with `query_posts` which should never be used.

Thirdly, your call to images should be inside your loop, not outside.

Ok, that cleared, you should run two loop here if you need other posts after the this first query.  You should have a look [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) on running multiple loops. But that all depends on what you need to achieve. Just one note, the codex page on multiple loops uses `query_posts` which you must not use. Stick with `WP_Query`

To come back to your loop for above, it should look something like this

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'band_member',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1 
  );

  $my_query = null;
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

       if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

       while ($my_query->have_posts()) :  $my_query->the_post();

      <-----get your images----->

 <?php
     endwhile;
  }

  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
```

**EDIT**

As you are a newbie, here is a great tip. When you develop a theme/plugin, or simply just add code to your theme, always set debug to true in wp-config.php. This will immediatly print errors to your screen if there are any. Just remember, never leave debug on true on a live site. Set to false immediatly after your done.

For further reading: [Debugging Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

**EDIT 2**

Having a look at the code you posted now, you can do that in one one loop. You should use [`rewind_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts) here

```
<?php
$args=array(
  'post_type' => 'band_member',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  );

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
echo '<div class="post-nav">'; 
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {

  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

  ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
echo '</div><!-- end post nav -->';

 $my_query->rewind_posts();

       while ($my_query->have_posts()) :  $my_query->the_post();

  ?> 

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"rel="bookmark" ><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a> 
   <?php
     endwhile;

?>
```

Comment: yes... this is almost exactly what I want. I can't add too much in the comments, so I'll edit my question with my final code. If you have a chance to see if it is ok, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: yes! it works, though being "green" I don't know if it is clear and concise.

Comment: I'll accept once we are done for sure!

Comment: There was a small syntax error in the code in EDIT 2. I've corrected it. You should be good to go. BTW, your code doesn't look bad in your edit. But you can do that in one one loop. Didn't know that you needed to do that what you have done. Hope this help

Comment: Also `rewind_posts()` should be `$my_query->rewind_posts()`

Comment: o crap yes, thanks @TheDeadMedic. Just came home from a course. Actually coded this while in class from my phone.

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

to save you from having to use wp_reset_query ...

```
    $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'band_member',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $show_band_members = get_posts( $args );
    if ($show_band_members) {
     echo '<div class="post-nav">'; 

       foreach ($show_band_members as $post) {
         setup_postdata( $post );
         ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" ><?php the_title(); ?></a>
         <?php
    }
}
echo "</div>";
```

An explanation of all of the parameters for get_posts can be found here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: You should add the relevant explanation to your answer